# Iteration with ls and space in name of file

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, space

I use bash on Ubuntu and I have some files in a folder, some with space in their name, other non.

I would like an array with file's name.
Example : [foo.txt, I am a file.txt, bar.jpg, etc.]

My code :

```
for x in "$(ls -1 test/)"; do 
    fileList+=($x)
done
```

I get : [foo.txt, I, am, a, file.txt, bar.jpg, etc.]

If I put `fileList+=("$x")` I get one line array [foo.txt I am a file.txt bar.jpg etc.].

How can I do to get what I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use shell globs? E.g.

```
for x in test/*; do
     ...
```

or

```
filelist=( test/* )
```

EDIT:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob
```

might be also wanted.

Comment: +1 To avoid prefixing each name with `test/`, use `pushd test; filelist=(*); popd` to change the working directory before expanding the glob.

Comment: It's perfect for me ! Thank you ;)
But I have an another question for other people.
How can you remove test/ in all string ?
Here I got tab like [test/foo.txt, test/bar.jpg, etc.].

Answer (score -1):

Try using read, like this:

```
ls | while read f ; do
   echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: The OP wanted a technique to handle spaces in filenames, which this does.

Comment: It only works for a subset of filenames that contain spaces, not all of them.

Comment: Thank you both for your advice - I shall try to reform my ways!